# Use global component in a async components

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have created a async component using Vue. It is loaded somewhere in the server. I would like to use some global component, like ui component[Vuetify], in the component, but the browser said it is not registered. can any one give me some advice.

The browser give me this error
Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

```
<template>
   <v-icon>home</v-icon>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
const RemoteComponent = new Promise(resolve => {
   // it is loaded from server
   resolve({
     template: '<v-icon>home</v-icon>'
   })
})
@Component({
   components: {
     RemoteComponent
   }
})
export default class LocalComponent extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Can anybody help me?